# Access Forbiden 403 en una ruta que si existe

Tags: php, laravel-5, php7, router

Estoy trabajando con laravel 5.8 y tengo en mis rutas algo como esto

```
Route::get('/probando/{term}', 'Dashboard\DashboardController@probando');
```

En mi controladora tengo lo siguiente:

```
public function probando($term)
{
    return new Response($term);
}
```

Mi finalidad con esta ruta es que por ejemplo pudiera filtrar determinado listado por un valor extraido de un campo de texto, y en mi controladora llamar a mi repositorio, realizar la consulta y devolver para atras el resultado. Pero me percaté que cuando en mi vista llenan el cuadro de texto cuyo valor es el que conformo la url en la parte **{term}** con 2 o más espacios, el resultado de mis solicitudes al servidor terminan como Access Forbidden 403, en resumen, si la url conformada termina de esta manera:

http://localhost/probando/%20%20  falla

Sin embargo si es:

http://localhost/probando/%20dariel%20 no falla

No quisiera hacerle trim al valor antes de hacer el ajax, ¿qué podria estar faltandome o cómo podria resolverlo?

Comment: Acabé de hacer una prueba con dichos valores y me funciona correctamente.

Comment: Que versión de laravel empleastes pk lo hice en la 5.8 que es con la que estoy trabajando y me muestra ese error, con la cache, las rutas y las vistas borradas con artisan optimize luego de modificar la ruta

Comment: Laravel 5.8.15, he intentado de varias formas y de todas me funciona.

Comment: Bueno yo tengo la 5.8.14, cerrare la pregunta entonces